# Arduino making a serial read string split and Then convert to Int

Tags: c++, string, split, serial-port, arduino

I've been trying split a string in arduino using many different ways, but nothing seems to work. My latest attempt:

```
String inData = "";
    int cPosition;
    String data[2];
    int count = 1;

    if (Serial.available() > 0) {

            int ssize = Serial.available();
            for(int i=0;i<ssize;i++){
              inData += (char)Serial.read(); 
            }

            do{
               cPosition =  inData.indexOf(':');
                if(cPosition != -1)
               {
                 data[count] = inData.substring(0,cPosition);
                 count++;
               } 
             }while(cPosition >=0);


            Serial.println(data[1]);

    }
```

I have two values coming in as "00:00" and I want to split them, but also to convert the split values to Int, as they will always be integers between 00 and 100.

Comment: You'll have to read the **entire** string first before you can convert it.  Your code does not ensure you got the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you tried `x=Serial.parseInt();` this read the next data if the an Integer it will find for exampel "fahijah123234fjrkaljf" come in in x will be 123234 same to next integer value

```
//incommeing: jsj123456asklfj654321faskl
int x,y;
x=Serial.parseInt();
y=Serial.parseInt();

Serial.println(x);//123456
Serial.println(y);//654321
```

to merege them use `strcat` or `sprintf`

http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseInt, 
http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseFloat